# How to make a 3 ✕ 3 grid using HTML and Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 20 element for a grid view. But I want only 3✕3 grid view, where there will be only 9 element in the view window. And the rest of the element should be placed in the right side of the window as a scrollable asset.**

No matter what the screen size is I want to show only the first 9 element in the grid.

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">ONE</div>
  <div class="card">TWO</div>
  <div class="card">THREE</div>
  <div class="card">FOUR</div>
  <div class="card">FIVE</div>
  <div class="card">SIX</div>
  <div class="card">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="card">NINE</div>
  <div class="card">TEN</div>
  <div class="card">ELEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">TWELVE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp try that

Comment: Wrap first 9 elements, and rest of elements to two separate divs. First will display elements in grid, second will show as scrollable content. Otherwise you will have to specifically target elements with `:nth-child`

Comment: @MUGABA i'm not seeing anything where i could specify only 9 element for the current window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the grid should flow vertically. And you can set it up like this with some calculation:

```css
.cards {
  /* how many columns on the first screen */
  --cols: 3;
  
  /* how many rows on the first screen */
  --rows: 3;
  
  /* grid gap */
  --gap: 5px;
  
  --width: calc((100% - var(--gap) * (var(--cols) - 1)) / var(--cols));
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-auto-columns: var(--width);
  grid-gap: var(--gap);
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">ONE</div>
  <div class="card">TWO</div>
  <div class="card">THREE</div>
  <div class="card">FOUR</div>
  <div class="card">FIVE</div>
  <div class="card">SIX</div>
  <div class="card">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="card">NINE</div>
  <div class="card">TEN</div>
  <div class="card">ELEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">TWELVE</div>
  <div class="card">THIRTEEN</div>
  <div class="card">FOURTEEN</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">ONE</div>
  <div class="card">TWO</div>
  <div class="card">THREE</div>  
  <div class="card">FOUR</div>
  <div class="card">FIVE</div>
  <div class="card">SIX</div>  
  <div class="card">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="card">NINE</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having more than 9 element. I can't change that.

Comment: What does this mean then "No matter what the screen size is I want to show only the first 9 element in the grid."

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is by using [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS selector on your `card` class. Since, you want to display only he first 9 cards in the container, you will have to hide the cards from 10th position onwards.

Consider `:nth-child(an + b)`. Here, the term `b` is the offset that you can specify to target cards. If you remove `a` and substitute the value of `b` as 10, it will target all the cards that appear as 10th child and later. The selector will be like so: `:nth-child(n + 10)`. This is a comparatively readable solution.

**Bonus Tip:** To make sure the cards show up as 3 x 3 grid, you can explicitly update `grid-template-columns` CSS property to be `repeat(3, 1fr)` instead of `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr))`

This is the final snippet:

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}

/* Hide card which occurs at 10th position and above */
.card:nth-child(n + 10) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">ONE</div>
  <div class="card">TWO</div>
  <div class="card">THREE</div>
  <div class="card">FOUR</div>
  <div class="card">FIVE</div>
  <div class="card">SIX</div>
  <div class="card">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="card">NINE</div>
  <div class="card">TEN</div>
  <div class="card">ELEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">TWELVE</div>
</div>
```